# How to update sizeHint of child widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a parent widget (retangular shape) and I want to place a child widget inside it. The position of the child should be configurable. The child is dynamically added to the parent widget when a button is pushed. When the button is pushed an instance of ChildWidget is created.

```
ChildWidget::ChildWidget(QWidget* pParent)
{
    setParent(pParent)

    show();

    SetChildPosition();

}

/*********** Protected methods ************/

void ChildWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pEvent)
{
   QPainter painter(this);
   painter.drawRect(0, 0, sizeHint().width() - 1, sizeHint().height() - 1);
   resize(sizeHint());

   QWidget::paintEvent(pEvent);
}

/*********** Private methods ************/

void ChildWidget::SetChildPosition()
{
   QPoint childPos = QPoint(parentWidget()->width() - sizeHint().width() - 5, 5);

   move(childPos);
}
```

At the moment the PaintEvent is called, the sizeHint() is correct (the rectangle drawn has the size of the widget. However it seems that sizeHint().width() = -1 in the "SetChildPosition" function. Is there any way to update the sizehint before I call the "SetChildPosition"?

Comment: I believe the correct way to handle this is to have a layout set for the parent widget and have the parent widget add the child widget to the layout, which will position the widget appropriately.

Comment: Hmm how would that work? The position of the childwidget should also be configurable. For example it should be possible to set it at pixel position (100,100).

Comment: Perhaps your question is missing important details, but I'm not sure how valid this use case is. For arbitrary widgets it seems bad form for the child widget force itself into its parent without using layouts. What if the child positions itself over crucial parts of the parent? How will the child respond appropriately when the parent is resized? For a set of user defined widget types then it may be possible for the child widgets to covey the desired positional information to the parent via new member functions.

Comment: However, I think you may be going down a wrong path and this sounds like a XY problem ([What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: The problems you describe are handled. First there is no "important area". If there was then setting the position to a different pixel value would fix this, The resizing is handled by the parentwidget; on a resize event, the  child widget is removed and added again.

Comment: What I'm trying is to put two widgets on top of eachother with the top widget having a configurable position and dynamically addition and removing of the top widget.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107232/discussion-between-james-adkison-and-frank).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using a layout as suggested.

I placed a QGridLayout on the parentWidget and placed the child widget inside of it. Then I used the 'setColumnMinimumWidth' and 'setRowMinimumHeight' of the QGridLayout to get it at the right pixel coordinate.